# LDAP error on bind method when trying to connect to LDAP

Tags: ldap

At my end(locally), I am using Sun ONE LDAP server, and where my application is deployed, they use MS AD. I store the values of User Name and Password (LDAP user name and password) in one table. In Sun ONE, I precede my user name with "cn=" and at my end I am able to connect to LDAP server, but where the application is deployed, the get bind error :-

```
Bind: Error: netscape.ldap.LDAPException: error result (49); 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 525, vece
```

I have my piece of code as follows for connection :-

```
try {  
    conn.connect(ldapHost,ldapPort);  
}  
catch(LDAPException ldapexception)  
{  
    ldapexception.printStackTrace(System.out);  
}  
try {  
    conn.bind(ldapVersion,loginDN,loginDN_Password);  
}  
catch(LDAPException ldapexception)  
{  
    ldapexception.printStackTrace(System.out);  
}
```

I am getting this error at bind.
I googled about this error, and I found that login credentials is the problem.

But I have verified at their end, the login credentials are correct, the only difference at my end and their end is that I precede my user name with "cn=" and they do not.
I tried doing the same, but still getting the same error.

Can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the BIND request is to exchange authentication information between client and server. If the BIND was successful, a SUCCESS result code is returned to the client in the BIND response, along with any controls. The *name* or *bind DN* must be an LDAP DN as defined in RFC4511 and RFC4514, therefore it must have the naming attribute (cn in your case).